# What's the alternative to using the now deprecated com.apple.eawt.ApplicationAdapter in Java Swing apps on the Mac?

Tags: java, macos, swing

Looks like apple has deprecated an api my app is using. Not sure how to work around this. The specific usage can be seen here:

http://code.google.com/p/jarzilla/source/browse/trunk/jarzilla/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jarzilla/Jarzilla.java#192

Comment: Usually when some API is deprecated, its documentation should suggest a replacement. (I do know nothing about Mac-specifics APIs, so I can't really help here.)

Comment: got it thanks. here's the diff that seems to still work for me: [link](http://code.google.com/p/jarzilla/source/diff?spec=svn31&r=31&format=side&path=/trunk/jarzilla/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jarzilla/Jarzilla.java&old_path=/trunk/jarzilla/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jarzilla/Jarzilla.java&old=30)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, a bit of googling got me [the API doc](https://coderanch.com/how-to/javadoc/appledoc/api/com/apple/eawt/ApplicationAdapter.html) (second hit for me), and it contains right in the first sentence:

> **Deprecated.** *replaced by AboutHandler, PreferencesHandler, AppReOpenedListener, OpenFilesHandler, PrintFilesHandler, QuitHandler, QuitResponse.*

(with links to the interfaces and class in mentioned).

So it looks like you should not use one object subclassing this abstract class, but several objects for the different purposes, and register them each with your Application object.

Comment: You don't need to use multiple objects: you can implement all the interfaces in a single class.

Comment: @Pont the point of the "Adapter" classes was that they had empty implementation for all the methods, and allowed you to override just the ones which were needed. This doesn't work with interfaces (at least did not work at the time I answered that, now we have default methods in interfaces).

Comment: True, with the new interface approach you get coarser granularity: you have to implement all or none of each interface, rather than cherry-picking methods. But this doesn't alter my point, which is that you don't need "several objects for the different purposes", as you wrote: you can use a single object which implements all the relevant interfaces.